# google plus auth returning error 401

Tags: authentication, google-plus

I am using Google plus auth to log in in web application. It is working properly, but for some time its return error 401. Error JSON is following. I view link [Error Description](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) but I did not understand what should I do.

```
{ 
   "error": 
           { "errors": 
              [ 
                { 
                  "domain": "global",
                  "reason": "authError", 
                  "message": "Invalid Credentials", 
                  "locationType": "header", 
                  "location": "Authorization" 
               } 
             ], 
            "code": 401, 
            "message": "Invalid Credentials" 
         } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error page indicated - your access token has likely expired. It sounds like you got an access token once, and are continuing to use it.

Access tokens expire after an hour. After that time, you either need to go through the auth flow again, or use the refresh token to get a new one.